# How to use the If condition in AWS SAM template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I have a use case where I have some currently running AWS Cloudformation stacks with active Cognito User Pools. For various reasons, I can't get rid of those pools, at the same time, going forward I want a newer naming convention for any new Cognito pools when deployed using the same template.

Here's the template file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: >
  Testing

# Global Parameters
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Default: dev
    Description: (required) Environment type
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - prod
  CognitoStack:
    Type: String
    Default: true
    Description: (required) Use default cognito or old cognito
    AllowedValues:
      - true
      - false

Mappings:
  HkCognitoUserPoolFixed:
    heka-dev:
      id: 'heka_dev_cognito_user_pool'
  HkCognitoUserPoolClientFixed:
    heka-dev:
      id: 'heka_dev_cognito_user_pool_client'

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 300
    MemorySize: 512
    Runtime: python3.8

Conditions:
  DefaultCognito: !Equals [ !Ref CognitoStack, true ]

Resources:
  # Cognito Stuff
  HkCognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      #      UserPoolName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}_${Environment}_cognito_user_pool
      UserPoolName: !If [ DefaultCognito, !Sub "${AWS::StackName}_${Environment}_cognito_user_pool", !FindInMap [ HkCognitoUserPoolFixed, !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'id' ] ]
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: 8
      UsernameAttributes:
        - email
      Schema:
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Name: email
          Required: true
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Name: phone_number
          Required: true
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Name: mrn
      AdminCreateUserConfig:
        AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: false
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
        - phone_number

  HkCognitoUserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      UserPoolId: !Ref HkCognitoUserPool
      #      ClientName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}_${Environment}_cognito_user_pool_client
      ClientName: !If [ DefaultCognito, !Sub "${AWS::StackName}_${Environment}_cognito_user_pool_client", !FindInMap [ HkCognitoUserPoolClientFixed, !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'id' ] ]
      GenerateSecret: false
      ExplicitAuthFlows:
        - ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
        - ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH
        - ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
        - ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH
```

Whenever I try to deploy the above template using these parameters I get an error.

Parameters:
`Environment=dev;CognitoStack=true`

Error:

```
Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: itcc-5, ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Template error: Unable to get mapping for HkCognitoUserPoolClientFixed::itcc-5::id
Create Change Set has failed: Command did not exit successfully, exit code: 1
itcc-5 has failed: Command did not exit successfully, exit code: 1
```

Looking at the error message, it looks like it is not evaluating my IF condition correctly, and going to the ELSE clause even when I am passing the `CognitoStack` as `true`.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your map `HkCognitoUserPoolClientFixed` does not have value for `itcc-5`.

Comment: @Marcin That's on purpose. I want it to use the formula in that scenario.

Comment: What formula? You code does not show any.

Comment: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}_${Environment}_cognito_user_pool"

Comment: I do not see how this formula has any connection to `!FindInMap [ HkCognitoUserPoolClientFixed, !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'id' ]` which causes your error.

Comment: @Marcin I realized what you were pointing to. I was expecting SAM to not evaluate the FindInMap in case the If condition is true. But as it turns out the both the clauses are evaluated and only one is used based on true/false of the if condition. It looks like I have to adandon this approach altogether to get my desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the parameter definition to:

```
  CognitoStack:
    Type: String
    Default: 'true'
    Description: (required) Use default cognito or old cognito
    AllowedValues:
      - 'true'
      - 'false'
```

and condition to:

```
Conditions:
  DefaultCognito: !Equals [ !Ref CognitoStack, 'true' ]
```

to prevent the parser from forcing a `String` 'true' or 'false' into a `Boolean`

Comment: I still get the same error: Reason: Template error: Unable to get mapping for HkCognitoUserPoolClientFixed::itcc-5::id